# Should we downvote misinformed questions, even if they are fixed?

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

I've been a member of Stack Overflow for about a year, and I've been question banned for about a month.

Here's the question that I especially am focusing on: [Does the change in lower bounds for the char type in C++14 break compatibility with ones' complement systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935246/does-the-change-in-lower-bounds-for-the-char-type-in-c14-break-compatibility-w)

While the original question is bad and deserved its initial 6 downvotes, I recently re-opened the question in an attempt to improve its quality and hopefully gain enough approval to remove my question ban. However, people still didn't seem to like it, even though I've posted all of my research and have already found the correct answer.

**Is the above answer an appropriate, yet misinformed question? If so, is it really kosher to simply downvote a question because the questioner is misinformed about the subject he/she is asking about? Even the original question did indeed have a reference link to the well-known `cpprefernce.com` C++ reference website.**

As an additional side note, even though many programmers often assert to "look at the standard" or "go read a book," I'd say that novice programmers often don't have the know-how or enough knowledge to adequately read the standard to the point where it can be used as a true, understandable reference source for them.

To go on further, since I have fixed the question, **is it really fair to keep the current reputation of the original question if it has been significantly revised and improved?**

Comment: Question-banned for about a month? March 9 was 7 weeks ago. Are you still banned?

Comment: I've been banned, I believe, for other factors as well, such as my question and answer deletes. However, this is 1 out of 6 questions that I have, and I'd like very much to rectify this one.

Comment: Personally, I don't see why 6 people downvoted your question. If I was a mod, I would remove those downvotes, delete the question or whatever. But I'm not a mod. Good luck!

Comment: @fredoverflow I agree with you, on both accounts, of what you said and didn't say. I don't see why it was down-voted, but I don't see any reason to up-vote it either.

Comment: @fredoverflow Mods can't remove votes, and OP can delete the question on their own if they wish.

Comment: @Yannis No, but I've made a strong attempt to improve the question. It's clearly outgrown its previous reputation. I was wondering if there was some way to determine whether the question has been greatly improved, since SO encourages question-banned users to fix their questions.

Comment: There's no point in having users have their questions heavily improved and yet not be recognized or at least compensated for it, especially if they're question-banned. Personally, I feel drained, as I've curated ALL of my questions so far and I'm still banned...

Comment: @Cinch It's not that easy for a question to come back from a -6, even if greatly improved. I appreciate the effort you've put in improving your question, but at the same time you have to realize that you've hit the ban because you have a history of low quality questions. Getting out of that hole shouldn't be easy.

Comment: @Yannis Even if I am a low-quality question asker, you can't deny that I've put a considerable amount of effort into actively improving my questions due to the ban. I actively try to clean my history by deleting my own insufficient questions or answers, and yet, I am still banned. I've risen in reputation and am now actively peer moderating SO through the review queue. How does this not qualify as "mitigating behaviour" to release or at least lighten the ban?

Comment: @Yannis And, although I may not be the most knowledgeable person, I am also very active on Lounge C++ and make an active effort to keep learning as a novice. If SO won't facilitate "dumb" questions, and I'm sure there's many of them, I propose that another sister site or some other site pop up to handle these questions.

Comment: @Cinch Eh, I didn't mean to call you a low quality asker. Sorry if it came out like that. My "low quality questions" remark was more about how the system perceives your contributions (solely based on the votes you received), rather than a comment on your efforts or knowledge.

Comment: SO should actively filter out the bad questions. Part of what makes this site such a good resource is that cream rising to the top. If your questions is not well asked, easy to understand, applicable to others etc. it shouldn't really be here. You efforts have been acknowledged, but the system has to rely on automatic process, perhaps one day a parole board can be put in place to lift question bans early.

Comment: @thecoshman Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291567/3325075

Comment: Visit the Help Center, read the "What topics can I ask about" section.  Focus on the word **practical** in the forth bullet.  You'll greatly fascinate [c++] visitors with a description of your one's complement machine and the C++11 compiler you use, upvotes guaranteed.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you suggesting that I need to "fascinate" [c++] visitors in order to get upvotes? I'm not playing a popularity contest with this; I'm trying to get my ban lifted so I can continue to use this site as a valid resource.

Comment: It is entirely up to you to bore them to tears, I wouldn't recommend it.  Your strategy to get your ban lifted just isn't a very good one.  Posting answers for a while is a better one.

Comment: @HansPassant The only reason I've decided to do this now because I've been actively on the site everyday since the ban to contribute. I've looked over my material, and it appears that I have fine answers, but as the mod mentioned in the linked related thread above, it's my questions that are the problem.

Comment: Quality over quantity.

Comment: @thecoshman I've refrained from posting additional questions because of this. However, my question history looks really bad and SO discourages the deletion of questions. What to do?

Comment: The ban is temporary, when it's over, only ask good questions.

Comment: @Cinch - its looks like the mob got to you. The mob is not held accountable for their actions. They are like a swarm of locust - they act as one and don't exercise individual thought. Its a well known problem on Stack Overflow. See [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953)

Answer (score 2):

> Should we downvote misinformed questions

Not automatically. If a question is down to a stupid mistake, such as a typo or just bad design, it's worth of a downvote. However, questions about a misunderstanding of what something in a specification etc. meant probably doesn't deserve downvoting, if it's a 'reasonable' mistake. If the OP is almost deliberately being obtuse, then I'd downvote them.

> even if they are fixed?

If any question or answer is substantially changed then yes, of course votes should be reconsidered either way. This is (partially at least) why SO has this feature. Normally votes are locked in forever (after a cool of) but edits will allow to revise you votes.

In you case in particular, I don't quite see why it got downvoted so strongly. If I was to blame anything it would be that you appear to be asking a rather in-depth question with out really showing you full grasp the situation. I'd argue that anyone who knows enough to ask what you asked, would know enough to answer it them self.

Comment: "I'd argue that anyone who knows enough to ask..." I am one of those users who are not ably equipped to wade through the C++ standard just yet. Even though I did some research, I still could not find the answer. Given a perfect world, I might have perfect access and perfect understanding of all given sources, but I don't. Should Stack Overflow penalize users for this?

Comment: Additionally, if SO only partially has this mitigation feature, I'd argue that a review queue for banned users who are actively editing their questions be considered.

Comment: Additionally, I'd say that a "typo or just bad design" can easily be fixed through an edit.

Comment: You missed my point. The question appears to be more like the the sort of noise you get form a child who just learnt the word "why" than the start of technically discussion between informed people.

Comment: Yes, typos can be easily fixed, but it is not upto the viewers to fix it. Downvotes should generally be accompanied with a reason. Else, as I am sure you would agree, it's not really helping anyone.

Comment: Typos are easily fixed, and many users often don't look back once they downvote a question. If the problem is easily fixed, but the downvote persists even after it is fixed, I would say that the downvoting mechanism is currently insufficient for conveying the intent of a downvote.

Comment: Let's not fixate too much on my one aspect. I do not think typos are the reason why you were downvoted.

Comment: But this isn't just about me. I just gave my question as an example.

Comment: And I gave my opinion on the matter. Yes people should revise votes if questions/answers change, but we can't force them. You can't auto clear votes, as that clearly allows exploitation. The current model is not forgiving, but I don't think it's that big a deal. You do not get questioned banned for one bad question.

Comment: Actually, as a new user, you do. My very first question was downvoted and I was question-banned.